# Implementing a report card generation system

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I want to create a system in `php` and `mysql` , that is supposed to calculate student grades and display the results, such that the school can print out a report card.

When a teacher logs onto the system, he/she will only see the students he/she teaches

I already have three tables in the database (`teachers` table, `students` table, `subjects` table).

A teacher teaches more than one subject and a teacher teaches more than one class.

How can I implement that in the database?

Comment: Looks like a nice, medium sized project. What do you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really appropriate for StackOverflow, but I will try to get you started by providing a first draft for your tables:

### Teacher

```
TeacherId INT NOT NULL Primary key Autogenerated
FirstName VARCHAR(100)
LastName VARCHAR(100)
```

### Student

```
StudentId INT NOT NULL Primary key Autogenerated
FirstName VARCHAR(100)
LastName VARCHAR(100)
```

### Subject

```
SubjectId INT NOT NULL Primary key Autogenerated
SubjectName VARCHAR(100)
```

### TeacherXSubject (association between teachers and subjects)

```
TeacherXSubjectId INT NOT NULL Primary key Autogenerated
TeacherId INT NOT NULL FK -> Teacher
SubjectId INT NOT NULL FK -> Subject
```

an unique key should be placed on (`TeacherId`, `SubjectId`)

### Class

```
ClassId INT NOT NULL Primary key Autogenerated
ClassName VARCHAR(100)
```

### TeacherXClass (classes one teacher may teach)

```
TeacherXClassId INT NOT NULL Primary key Autogenerated
TeacherId INT NOT NULL FK -> Teacher
ClassId INT NOT NULL FK -> Class
```

an unique key should be placed on (`TeacherId`, `ClassId`)

### ClassXStudent (the classes a student may attend)

```
ClassXStudentId INT NOT NULL Primary key Autogenerated
ClassId INT NOT NULL FK -> Class
StudentId INT NOT NULL FK -> Student
Grade INT    -- type may depend on how the grade looks (numeric vs. A, B, ...)
```

For the first request: see the students he/she teaches

```
SELECT S.*
FROM Student S
   INNER JOIN ClassXStudent CxS ON CxS.StudentId = S.StudentId
   INNER JOIN TeacherXClass TxS ON TxS.ClassId = CxS.ClassId
WHERE T.TeacherId = <current teacher id>
```

Give it a try and come back with more targeted questions :).

Comment: Be sure to have the proper indexes for many-to-many tables.  [See my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: @RickJames - this is correct, especially for large number of records. However this post was intended as quick-start and tried to keep it minimal :)